# USB CDC-ACM on STM32 device not registering on Linux

Tags: usb, stm32, stm32cubemx

Working with the STM32L062 Cortex-M0 and CubeMX the generated USB CDC-ACM code works fine in Windows.  With loopback code running on the STM32 and TerraTerm running on Windows characters typed in the terminal window correctly echo back.  However, when this same system is then plugged into a laptop running Ubuntu, the device fails to enumerate.  Even worse, the system doesn't appear to respond to the connection whatsoever- no new messages appear via `dmesg` that even a failed enumeration is going on.  Given that the code used is generated by CubeMX wizards it is difficult to know what to start to troubleshoot.  Any suggestions?

As an aside, this isn't the first issue presented by CDC-ACM drivers.  Implementing a USB CDC-ACM stack for a PIC32MM processor, data can be sent to the host but not received from the host, however, if the driver is switched to plain vanilla CDC then data can be sent both ways no problem.  So it seems maybe Ubuntu has some issues with the default USB drivers, but either way, it's very odd that the ST driver gets zero response at all from the system.